# This should be true concerning Lebesgue measure, no?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Take R^n with its associated Lebesgue measure. Let A be a set of positive measure. Do there exist points x and x' in A such that x'>>x, or x' is strictly larger in each component than x? Something tells me this must be true, and I've been working on it all day. Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Try this on math.stackexchange.com. it's not appropriate for this site.

Comment: Hint: Consider translations of $A$ by $c\vec{v}$ where $\vec{v}$ is in the positive orthant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the relation $\gg$ correctly, then the answer is yes.  This follows from the following proposition.

> Let $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a Lebesgue-measurable set of positive measure. Then the difference set $D(A) = \{ x-y \mid x,y \in A \}$ contains an open ball about the origin.

This is a standard exercise in measure theory (at least in $\mathbb{R}$).  You can find several proofs of it on math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38902/the-set-of-differences-for-a-set-of-positive-lebesgue-measure

In particular, $D(A)$ contains points whose coordinates are entirely positive.  Therefore there exist points $x,y \in A$ such that $x \gg y$.

Comment: Please use $\gg$ instead of $>>$.

Comment: An alternate proof would use the Lebesge density theorem.